# PL/SQL Running all If cases

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a script that takes, among other things, a user input variable for what type of `INSERT` to execute:

```
DECLARE
    givenExp    ExpMast.expNum%NUMBER;
    paymentType VARCHAR(10);

BEGIN
    givenExp := &desiredExpNum;
    SELECT * From ExpMast WHERE expNum = givenExp;

    paymentType := &Type_of_Payment;
    IF(paymentType = 'CARD') THEN
        INSERT INTO ExpByCC(givenExp, &CType, &CCNum, &Amt);

    ELSIF(paymentType = 'CASH') THEN
        UPDATE TABLE ExpMast
        SET CashAmt = &PaymentAmount
        WHERE ExpNum = givenExp;

    END IF;
END;
/
```

However, when I execute the script, it runs both of the `IF` statements. I have tried it with entering both `'CASH'` and `'CARD'` but it runs both no matter what. I even changed it to use 1 and 0 instead of strings, but the same error persists.

EDIT: Removing the `ELSIF` does nothing, as entering complete random garbage still sends the code into the `INSERT` statement after the first `IF`. The code is for some reason completely ignoring my `IF`.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. Also, your SELECT statement will raise an error since there is no INTO clause.

Comment: How would I need to have the INTO set up for it to work? I'm new to PL/SQL statements, and a nearly identical statement works in regular SQL.

Comment: Yes, that will work in SQL, but not PL/SQL. You need some place for the values you're selecting from ExpMast to go. But since you don't seem to need anything else for this statement, you can just get rid of that line. Unless your CType, CCNum, and Amt are supposed to come from there?

Comment: I don't actually strictly need anything from there, it's just there to remind the user of what other items have the same ExpNum. So basically it should just print the results, nothing else.

Comment: Also when you say you don't see how that's possible, do you mean what I'm asking isn't possible, or that you don't understand why I am having this problem?

Comment: You're right, it would be highly weird if both the IF and ELSIF branches are executed. So the most plausible explanation is that they're not both executed and it just looks that way. Please remember that SQL\*Plus prompts for all substitution values before executing anything. Prompts for variables in both branches doesn't mean that both branches are executed. If this explanation doesn't satisfy you will need to post a reproducible test case: show table structures, starting data state, values for input variables and the end data state.

Comment: Please understand that the `update` statement is not getting executed here. Your editor - probably SQL* Plus is prompting for the substitution variables wherever it finds it.In both your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` you've got substitution variables. So, as soon as you run the script, you are prompted to enter all the required values for all placeholders containing the '&' symbol. One solution is to prompt for all your substitution variables in one place at the beginning and then run other statements

Comment: It just can't run both the insert and update statement. Also, the block you've provided won't compile, so you're running something we're not seeing here.